# Jquery - Pass data to inline functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, parameters

This is probably really simple, and the answer is probably really obvious, but I'm drawing a blank here.

I have an array of HTML elements that I am binding the .hover() event to. I need to know what array index was used by the event.

So let's say element[7] is hovered over, how do I pass the number 7 to that function?

Here is what I am using:

```
for (i=0; i<statecount; i++) {
    $("#"+imagemap[i][0]).hover(function() {
        // Mouse enters HTML element

        alert(i); 

        // "i" returns 15, which makes sense because "i" 
        // has changed since this function was defined.
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a closure as a wrapper to save state.

```
for (i = 0; i < statecount; i+=1)
{
  (function(i){
    $('#'+imagemap[i][0]).hover(function () {
      alert(i);
    });
  }(i));
}
```

Comment: This works, does this little trick have a name? I tried searching for jquery wrapper but it shows results for the wrap() function, etc.

Thanks

Comment: @RadGH: JavaScript self-calling function I believe...or self-invoking function

Comment: "immediately invoked function expression": http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: Thanks for the comments, it's difficult to find things like this by just using google. Hehe

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't answer your question, you can get a handle to the object that was hovered over using `this` inside the function:

```
for (i=0; i<statecount; i++) {
    $("#"+imagemap[i][0]).hover(function() {
        alert(this);
    }
}
```

You might want to use `$(this)` if you want the JQuery object.

Comment: That's not what he asked for specifically, no, but it might be what he wants.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I knew about "this" already (heh). I considered looping through my array and comparing "this" to the element of the array, but couldn't get that to work - and if it did it would have been a very clunky way of doing it. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using >= jQuery 1.6, `$.proxy` will curry parameters:

```
$.proxy(function(a, b, c) { ... }, this, 'argA', 'argB', 'argC');
```

so you could write it like this:

```
for (i=0; i<statecount; i++) {
    $("#"+imagemap[i][0]).hover($.proxy(function(index, event) {
        // Mouse enters HTML element

        alert(index); 
    }, this, i));
}
```

Note that this pushes the event the end of the argument list.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful because this is easy to screw up:

```
var hoverer = function(i) {
  return function() {
         alert(i); 
  };
};

for (i=0; i<statecount; i++) {
        $("#"+imagemap[i][0]).hover(hoverer(i));
}
```